# pandas: how to summarize unequal size datasets?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have datasets of *different size* eg `X_1 = [1,2,3]` and `X_2 = [4,5,6,7,8]`. I would like to create a dataframe with summary variables (mean, std, etc), with one dataset per row, and on statistic per column. How can I do that in pandas?

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? This seems rather trivial, just loop through your sets of dataframe and calculate the summary variables and create the new dataframe from that point.

Comment: @Idlehands: what should I "try"? either there exists some functionality, or not. I don't wanna loop, that defeats the purpose of using a library

Comment: Please check the help center for How to Ask and provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could have at least explicitly say you didn't want a loop that I suggested, and what sort of research you had done prior to asking the question so at least we had some directions.  I'm sure you are aware of [ask], but I feel higher reps users shouldn't be exempt from following the guideline.  If anything they should be setting examples for new users to follow on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @G.Anderson: there's no minimal example here, I'm asking whether a function exists. If I could provide an example,  there would be no question

Comment: @Idlehands: it's not a matter of rep. The guidelines exist to avoid "do my homework for me" questions. In this case I'm just asking what's the proper way of doing that. Clearly there's a thousand ways it could be done manually, but there's no point in writing code that I know is bad, just to be able to ask how it could be better. Turns out, the answer is aggregating on `pd.concat`, instead of multiple for-loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate `Series` into a `DataFrame` and then use `.agg`. `NaN` will be inserted to fill cells with unequal length, but most `pandas` agg functions will ignore them by default for calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in [X_1, X_2]], axis=1, keys=['X_1', 'X_2'])

df.agg(['mean', 'std']).T
#     mean       std
#X_1   2.0  1.000000
#X_2   6.0  1.581139
```

If you have many lists, probably better to hold them in a dictionary to avoid writing out both the keys and lists separately

Comment: This still extend the each dataframe to the max length one and fill by NaN ,The problem will happen when we count the len of df

Comment: @W-B using `'count'` will ignore `NaN` when aggregating to still give the correct number of elements, but `'size'` would give the incorrect number.

Comment: count is fine , but (length) will cause the problem .

Comment: For example , it there is NaN in the original X_1 at the last row , should w do toget the length of df

Comment: I agree, having the MultiIndex is safer in general, @blue_note should probably move the check to the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

I will using `describe`

```
df=pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in [X_1, X_2]], axis=0, keys=['X_1', 'X_2'])# notice here I am using axis=0 rather than 1 
df.groupby(level=0).describe()
Out[442]: 
     count  mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
X_1    3.0   2.0  1.000000  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0
X_2    5.0   6.0  1.581139  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

---

special cases

```
X_1 = [1,2,np.nan] 
X_2 = [4,5,6,7,8]

df=pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in [X_1, X_2]], axis=0, keys=['X_1', 'X_2'])
df.groupby(level=0).size()
Out[445]: 
X_1    3
X_2    5
dtype: int64
```